# MATLAB : Error using histc. First Input must be a real non-sparse numeric array

Tags: matlab

I've got the error of "Error using histc. First Input must be a real non-sparse numeric array" from the following codes.

```
N=10^4;
d=rand(1,N)>0.5;
symbols=unique(d);
probs = histc(d,symbols)./numel(d);
```

P/s: I try to generate using randsrc before. It did worked.But, I'm hoping not to use randsrc because it will affect my code later on. Any ideas on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For me this code works properly. Maybe try to convert from logical to full double vector first: `probs = histc(double(d(:)),symbols)./numel(d);` Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
N=10^4;
d=double(rand(1,N)>0.5);
symbols=unique(d);
probs = histc(d,symbols)./numel(d);
```

Comment: Thank You for the feedback. I don't get the error anymore.